# How can I get total documents/objects retrieved from an MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT something.* FROM someting WHERE TRUE AND something.is_active=1 ORDER BY long_id DESC`. The query above will retrieve some objects and document.

**Is it possible to get the total number of documents/objects from that query before retrieving the documents/objects themselves?**

The case here is that table "something" can have over 100,000 documents/objetcs hence cannot be handled by PHP (returning fatal error insufficient memory). So I want to know how many documents/objects will be retrieved from the query.

I have tried any combinations of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT something.* FROM something WHERE TRUE AND something.is_active=1 ORDER BY long_id DESC
SELECT COUNT(SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT something.*) FROM something WHERE TRUE AND something.is_active=1 ORDER BY long_id DESC
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT COUNT(something.*) FROM something WHERE TRUE AND something.is_active=1 ORDER BY long_id DESC
```

but always have this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...`.

Comment: Show what you've tried with `COUNT` and the full error.

Comment: Edited. I don't think they are matters though.

Comment: But that's your whole question...

Comment: You mean you want to know the total rows without fetching them right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM something WHERE something.is_active=1
```

Just simplify your query and count all of the results. `DISTINCT something.*` makes no sense either (unless your table doesn’t have a primary key, which I doubt is the case).

Comment: @david sure. But DISTINCT on every column of a table...?

Comment: unfortunately, the OP doesn't mention the fields in the table

Comment: True. It’s plausible that the table doesn’t have a primary key in which case that would make sense, but otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT something.*) FROM something WHERE something.is_active=1 ORDER BY long_id DESC
```

Since you use `COUNT`, there is no need to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Also, I remove `TRUE` in where clause because it is unnecessary.

Comment: ORDER BY does nothing here

Comment: How can you know that `ORDER BY` does nothing? We don't even know the result of the OP's query. Maybe the OP needs it.

Comment: How would the order affect a count?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, you are right. It just return a single value. But, I will keep my answer.